# What should be the proper declaration of array while finding the largest number in array?

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration

**C++** This is my code in **C++** for finding the largest number in array. When I was running in my IDE then there was no compilation error but it was not giving me output. I think the problem is in the declaration of array at line 8. I replaced the array declaration from line 8 to line 11 then it is  working fine in my IDE. So I didn't get it that why the declaration of array was not working at line 8?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int largest_in_array(int a[], int n);

int main() // main function
{
    int n; // User will enter the size of array 
    int arr[n]; // Line 8
    cout << "Enter the size of array: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
              // Line 11
    cout << "\nEnter the elements of array: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // This loop will run for each element of array that user wants to enter
    {
        cout << "Enter the " << (i + 1) << " element:";
        cin >> arr[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Elements are: [";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // Prints the elements of array
    {
        // cout << "Enter the " << (i + 1) << " element:";
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        // cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "]";

    int res = largest_in_array(arr, n); //Function call
    cout << "\nLargest element in array is: " << arr[res] << endl;
    return 0;
}

int largest_in_array(int a[], int n) // function that will return the index of largest element in array
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[max] < a[i])
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: You declare `int arr[n];` before the user enters `n` - what value do you expect `n` to have at that point? Also `int arr[n]` is a VLA which is not part of standard C++. Make it `std::vector<int> arr(n);` instead

Comment: In line 8 the input has not been read. How is the program supposed to know information not yet present? Note that regardless of the order of the statements this only works with a non-standard extension to C++. The C++ standard only allows for fixed size array declarations where the number of elements is known at compile time. You should use a data structure that allows you to dynamically allocate the elements, e.g. `std::vector<int>`

Comment: Recommended reading: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/2752075), [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2752075)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You declare int `arr[n];` before the user has entered a value into `n`. `n` has an indeterminate value when you read it and create `arr`.
- You don't check that the user enters a positive value into `n`. Zero and negative sized arrays are not valid.

Other points:

- `bits/stdc++.h` is not a standard header which makes your program not portable. Use the proper header files, like `iostream` etc.
- `arr[n]` is a *Variable Length Array* (VLA) which is not part of standard C++. Make it a `std::vector<int> arr(n);` instead.
- The use of `std::endl` is unnessesary. There is no need to flush the output streams here. Use `\n` instead.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

int largest_in_array(const std::vector<int>& a) {
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if(a[max] < a[i]) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main() // main function
{
    int n; // User will enter the size of array
    std::cout << "Enter the size of array:\n";

    // check that input succeeds and that the value is valid
    if(!(std::cin >> n) || n < 1) return 1;

    std::vector<int> arr(n);
    std::cout << "\nEnter the elements of array:\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the " << (i + 1) << " element:";
        if(!(std::cin >> arr[i])) {
            std::cout << "invalid input, bye bye\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Elements are: [";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "]";

    int res = largest_in_array(arr); // Function call
    std::cout << "\nLargest element in array is: " << arr[res] << '\n';
}
```

That said, you could however use the standard algorithm [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) instead of writing your own. It returns an *iterator* to the maximum element.
You could also make use of range-based for loop when you don't need to know the index in the array, as in your second loop.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n; // User will enter the size of array
    std::cout << "Enter the size of array:\n";
    if(!(std::cin >> n) || n < 1) return 1;

    std::vector<int> arr(n);
    std::cout << "\nEnter the elements of array:\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // This loop will run for each element of
                               // array that user wants to enter
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the " << (i + 1) << " element:";
        if(!(std::cin >> arr[i])) {
            std::cout << "invalid input, bye bye\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Elements are: [";
    for(auto value : arr) {          // a range-based for loop
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";

    auto res = std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    std::cout << "Largest element in array is: " << *res << '\n';

    std::size_t index = std::distance(arr.begin(), res);
    std::cout << "which has index " << index << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have `int n` on line 8 it is initialized when you use it to create the array. When `n` is initialized explicitly, it's value is undefined behavior. You may be creating an array **larger** than the `n` you inputted on line 10, resulting in the array having extra random junk, it may be smaller meaning your program read memory it really shouldn't, etc.